# How to test chrome.alarms api?

Tags: testing, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that uses several [alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) scheduled to trigger every hour, every day, etc.
Testing alarm-related features is a pain for our testers, because they need to change system time. What they actually do:

1. close chrome
2. open system date/time dialog
3. move system date ahead
4. open chrome

Could anybody suggest more convenient ways to make functional tests of chrome alarms?

We check on both windows and OSX.

Comment: A shell script that changes system date + something like Selenium ChromeDriver might help.

Comment: You did not specify which OS(es).

Comment: So I guess the most important part of the question is whether it's possible to test without closing Chrome.